# How to disable a region when a child window pops up in another region in prism mef wpf

Tags: wpf, prism, mef

I have two regions in Shell- Toolbar region and content region.
Content region has many views- parent and child windows. When a child window pops up Toolbar region is not disabled. What should be done to disable the Toolbar region?

Answer (score 0):

You can bind your viewModel's main content's attribute `IsEnabled` to a boolean property `IsPopupGone`.  In the constructor of your toolbar subscribe EventAggregator to an event `PopupWindowStateChanged` and payload as a boolean.  Then when your popup window(s) display, publish this event with True, and when closed publish as False.

```
private bool isPopupGone = true; // default/original state assumed to be no childs showing
public bool IsPopupGone
{ 
    get { return isPopupGone; } 
    set { isPopupGone = value; /* implement notifypropertychanged */ }
}

public ToolbarViewModel(IEventAggregator eventAggregator)
{
    EventAggregator = eventAggregator;
    EventAggregator.GetEvent<PopupWindowStateChanged>().Subscribe(UpdateEnabledState);
}

public void UpdateEnabledState(bool isPopupShowing)
{
    IsPopupGone = !isPopupShowing;
}

<UserControl x:Class="ToolbarView">
    <Menu IsEnabled="{Binding Path=IsPopupShown, Mode=OneWay}">
        ...
    </Menu>
</UserControl>
```

And the popup just needs to do the below when appropriate, either when created/showing (true), or when closing (false)

```
EventAggregator.GetEvent<PopupShowingChanged>().Publish(true); // false
```

I don't like the naming of the property IsPopupGone, I'd rather have IsPopupShowing and use a converter in the XAML, but this may be easier as an answer for you/others.